# Find this WordPress element in code editor

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I am a PHP programmer, but not a WordPress programmer. Can someone help me find out where in the code editor of WordPress to find the **Custom HTML** widget in the **Sidebar**? The purpose is because I want to offer to sell my own ad space (instead of using AdSense, etc.). Once I find out how to edit the PHP of this element, then I can have it randomly show an ad (based on ad space I've sold). I don't particularly need help with the coding. I think that's not a problem for me; however, I will take advice on better ways to do it. Here's an example of how I would do it (I would definitely do it differently if it was my own programmed site, rather than WordPress)...

```
$adsAvailable = 4; // number of customers or ads to show
$adsRandom = rand(1,$adsAvailable);

if($adsAvailable == 1) { // show tracking link and image here of customer / ad # 1 }
elseif($adsAvailable == 2) { // show tracking link and image here of customer / ad #2 }
// etc.
```

Help with the code is appreciated, but my main question is, where do I find the element Custom HTML in the Sidebar widget within code editor? Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[Image is a screenshot of the portion of the site I'm looking to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYckS.jpg)

Comment: The Custom HTML widget is a core WordPress widget so modifying its code directly isn't recommended: you'll lose all the modifications the next time you update WordPress (and you'll want to update WordPress regularly). Instead, you could: a) build your own widget, or b) load your ads via AJAX and continue using the Custom HTML widget as usual.

Comment: Ok. If I load my ads via AJAX, how can I place those ads in the sidebar?

Comment: If I create a separate php file and include it in the core WordPress file, then upon updating the site, I only have to add `<?php include('ads.php'); ?>`, right?

Comment: No. Use AJAX to inject your ads into the HTML container. That's how I would do it if I wanted to use the Custom HTML widget anyways.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. Still doesn't tell me where the HTML widget is in WordPress. I want to use the sidebar for the ad space instead of something like header or footer (which is easy to find) because I want to keep my website clean and unobtrusive from ads.